# gradle import elasticsearch 7.6.1, but imported 7.6.1 and 6.4.3 together

Tags: elasticsearch, gradle

I create a project with spring boot project and gradle. 
In build.gradle file, I import elasticsearch rest high level client like this:

```
compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client', version: '7.6.1'
```

But after building, I found it imported elasticsearch jars both version 7.6.1 and 6.4.3.
I removed elasticsearch folders from in local gradle repository folder, and build again. But the result is the same.

I don't know why version 6.4.3 imported. I don't use any other elasticsearch related jars in my project. 
Who can tell me where the 6.4.3 jars come from? How can I remove them?

It seems Spring dependency-management-plugin control the version of es, and ignored my configuration in build.gradle. How could it do this? How can I resolve the problem?

[screenshot from IDEA, it shows the elastic jars in two versions imported together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHfZs.png)

Comment: Could it be a transitive dependency? Is something else pulling in elasticsearch? What do you get from `gradle -q dependencies` ?

Comment: I resolved it by add this in build.gradle:
    dependencyManagement {
        dependencies {
            dependency 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:7.6.1'
            dependency 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:7.6.1'
            dependency 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.6.1'
        }
    }

Comment: Good stuff. I think one side effect of that is that a different version that's pulled in transitively is ignored, and your specific version is used instead.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by adding these lines to build.gradle:

```
dependencyManagement {
    dependencies {
        dependency 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:7.6.1'
        dependency 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:7.6.1'
        dependency 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.6.1'
    }
}
```